# Swift tuple declaration in a protocol

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, reactive-swift

I have a tuple variable in my code, that comes from ReactiveSwift:

```
class MyClass {
   var (signal, signalSender) = Signal<Bool, Error>.pipe()
}
```

How can I declare that variable tuple in a protocol?

Similar like this (doesn't work):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   var (signal, signalSender): Signal<Bool, Error> { get set }
}
```

There appears a syntax error: *"Getter/setter can only be defined for a single variable"*

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type of your property should be tuple, not just declaration of some class/struct. So, look what your `pipe()` returns. It should return tuple with two types

```
func pipe() -> (Type1, Type2) { ... }
```

To protocol declaration use these two types

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var tuple: (signal: Type1, signalSender: Type2) { get set }
}
```

then implement this protocol to your class and assign it with return value of `pipe()`

```
class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var tuple: (signal: Type1, signalSender: Type2) = Signal<Bool, Error>.pipe() 
}
```

then when you need get element of tuple, just use

```
tuple.signal
tuple.signalSender
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition is defining two properties, and then happens to be assigning them from a tuple, but they're still two independent properties. You can see this if you use `init` syntax instead (the syntax you're using is just a convenience for this):

```
class MyClass {
    var signal: ...
    var signalSender: ...

    init() {
        let (signal, signalSender) = Signal<Bool, Error>.pipe()
        self.signal = signal
        self.signalSender = signalSender
   }
}
```

What you want here is:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var signal: ... { get set }
    var signalSender: ... { get set }
}
```

The type of `signal` and `signalSender` are not `Signal<Bool, Error>`. They're whatever `pipe()` returns.

You can still conform to that protocol with the syntax that MyClass is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable like this as long the single accepts only one variable, so this variable will be tuple.

```
protocol MyProtocol {

   var varName: Signal<(signal: Bool, signalSender: Error)> { get set }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define your protocol like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype E: Error
    var signal: Signal<Bool, E> {get}
    var signalObserver: Signal<Bool, E>.Observer {get}
}
```

and then in your conformed class:

```
class TestClass: MyProtocol {
    var (signal, signalObserver) = Signal<Bool, NSError>.pipe() //you can replace NSError with your custom error type
}
```